# How to compare databases?

Tags: postgresql, comparison, meld

I tried using `meld` on two dumps from two different databases from the same RDBMS, but it seems that those dumps are not comparable because not being canonical.

I tried both `pg_dump ...` (standard) and `pg_dump -a ...` (only data) but both seem not being canonical, they are not so different, but the side to side difference shows a lot of false positives.

I searched for an applicable option in `pg_dump` without success, maybe a special tool is needed for this?

Comment: Every db platform I've worked with required an external utility for this purpose, and Postgre is probably no differant. check this out: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/postgresql/datacompare/

Comment: Okay, but maybe for `pg_dump` maintainer adding an option for canonical output would be no big deal. If `meld` is OK, and it is, isn't it the natural approach trying to leverage it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution may be rather manual:

1. Dump the schema and table names.
2. Loop over schema and table names, dumping each in turn (making sure to **order by a set of columns giving a unique ordering**) to the same file or a file per table.
3. Repeat for the other database.

This should get you an easily comparable output.

Comment: I like it and at some point it's sure I'll give a try. However I'm not sure the schema will be comparable (they are mutant schemas of hundreds of tables and constraints), but I like very much the idea of passing an ORDER BY or something to the dump instruction. It would be needed also an additional step to abbreviate binary/base64/blob columns, but there should be alternatives for coding that, e.g. `awk`, `sed`, Python.

Comment: Just get the checksum of binary or other excessively long columns. At least then you can tell with certainty whether the values are different.

Comment: I don't know a way of sorting the rows other than with an external script that performed the row sort for each table (lines between lines matching "^COPY" and "^\\.") and copied verbatim all the remaining information in a `pg_dump` text dump.

Comment: You can do `order by 1, 2, 3, [etc]` to simply order by all the columns.

Comment: I was thinking of using only `pg_dump`... Yeah but having dirtrees support in the comparison tool, is OK dumping the tables' contents to single files using `psql`. But I will try not to use that approach, so that the binary checksum will be a script option, it will be possible to have a single file, and that single file would be restorable whenever binary columns would not have been checksummed. I'm trying to develop something asap...

Comment: Favoring my approach of sorting the rows outside SQL am having results enough good for me, to date. [Source](http://ow.ly/DRqXV).

Comment: Note to self: fix that broken link. :/

Comment: Done!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Excellent! Would you mind setting this answer as accepted?

Comment: Can't do that because it seems I was forced to sort out `COPY` lines at the Shell level. I upvoted aeons ago though.